# Kubernetes add GPU support, does the cpu node need install nvidia driver and nvidia docker?

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia-docker

I am new to Kubernetes. Now I need to add 2 nodes with GPU. The origin environment is 5 cpu node. Should I install nvidia driver and nvidia docker in the 5 cpu node too?

Comment: can you check this document. Kubernetes installation part is very well documented.https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/kubernetes-install-guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Shashank Pai mentioned, take a look at NVIDIA documentation [Here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/kubernetes-install-guide/index.html) in order to check all the advantages of using NVIDIA GPUs in Kubernetes cluster.